# stringstream segmentation fault

Tags: g++, stringstream

Using linux and g++.

This works:

```
stringstream ss;
for (int k = 1; k < 1000; k++){
}
```

This should also works but result in "segmentation fault":

```
for (int k = 1; k <1000; k++){
     stringstream ss;
}
```

Why?

Comment: I copied the second code snippet into a main() method, compiled and ran it (also using linux), but I didn't get a segfault. Could you post the full code that's causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Antonio Perez for your reply.

Actually my code was exactly this:

```
#pragma pack(1)
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        std::stringstream ss;
    }
}
```

Amazingly if I displace the #pragma pack(1) like this:

```
#include <sstream>
#pragma pack(1)
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        std::stringstream ss;
    }
}
```

...then no error occurs!

Is there a possible (non-bug) reason for why sstream does not permit packing of its structure?